# Margin Notes in Unicode RTL

Tags: marginpar, hebrew, marginnote, bidi

I've mentioned this problem in a previous (unanswered) question, but this is a more extensive and specific.

I'm trying to get margin notes in a Hebrew document, so I'm using the `libertine` `polyglossia`, and `bidi` packages for that. I would like to make margin notes in certain places. Most of the time `\marginpar{}` works for that, but frequently I find myself in a float environment that requires `\marginnote{}`. As you can see below `\marginnote{}` has been placing the margin notes in odd places, if they show up at all. Perhaps it's being confused by the `bidi` package?

How can I get a margin note with a floating environment? I'm open to using either `marginpar` or `marginnote` as long as it works. Thanks.

BTW: I assume a similar

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{book}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{.5in}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage{bidi}


\begin{document}
דת הגולשות פילוסופיה, כלל את היום לכאן, חפש ב שמות באגים פולנית. תרומה המחשב מדינות אחר בה. כדי מועמדים קרימינולוגיה ביוטכנולוגיה מה, היסטוריה אנתרופולוגיה קרן אם. של כימיה רפואה זכר. אנא עזרה מדויקים אווירונאוטיקה דת.
\marginpar{marginpar}

לוח על ביולוגיה העריכהגירסאות, בקר אם מוגש בדפים הגרפים. צ'ט את יידיש מיזמי אקטואליה. מה כלל תרבות ספורט
\marginnote{marginnote}
, דת אנא ציור פוליטיקה טכנולוגיה. על כלל תרומה הנדסת. ספורט מושגי היסטוריה שער מה, המחשב בגרסה תבניות מה קרן, אם אחד לכאן למתחילים ביוטכנולוגיה.

\begin{mdframed}
מלא יוני חרטומים אם, שער הנדסת המקושרים אנתרופולוגיה מה. אם 
\marginnote{marginnnote}
אחד למתחילים מיתולוגיה, ציור כלכלה צ'ט בה. החלה כניסה מה כלל, סדר היום ברית ואלקטרוניקה אל. אינטרנט המקושרים מה מלא, רבה עיצוב המשפט מבוקשים או. אנא
\marginnote{marginnnote}
  דת חשמל גיאוגרפיה פסיכולוגיה, גם אנא לראות המקובל, הבהרה מתמטיקה והגולשים את אתה. צ'ט אל ריקוד שדרות שימושי, את מיזם מועמדים פוליטיקה מלא.

עזרה המחשב המזנון בה עזה, את יסוד הסביבה אגרונומיה אתה, ברית הבאים והנדסה ב קרן. מתוך מועמדים דת בדף, את שכל קבלו האנציקלופדיה העריכהגירסאות. מדריכים
\marginnote{marginnote}
 ויקימדיה את עזה, כיצד ציור ארץ אם, טיפול לתרום סדר מה. שתי אם צילום תקשורת, לחבר המחשב מדריכים ב היא. מדע בה הראשי לימודים פילוסופיה.

\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After reporting the problem to the author of `marginnote` he stated, that `bidi` does not support `marginnote`. From [release 1.2b](https://komascript.de/marginnote) of `marginnote`, which is already available [from CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) and as [MiKTeX package](https://miktex.org/packages/marginnote) and which is also part of TeX Live 2017 pretest, it does support `bidi` and all other packages that set `\if@RTL`.

Here is a workaround for `marginnote` up to release 1.2a, that adds such support but would result in errors if `bidi` has not been loaded. So please use it with care:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{book}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{.5in}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage{bidi}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackagelater{marginnote}{2017/01/01}{}{%
  \usepackage{xpatch}
  \xapptocmd{\@mn@margintest}{%
    \if@RTL
      \typeout{RTL mode detected}%
      \ifx\@mn@currxpos\@empty\else
        \edef\@mn@currxpos{\the\dimexpr\pdfpagewidth-\@mn@currxpos\relax}%
      \fi
    \else
      \typeout{LTR mode detected}%
    \fi
  }{}{}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
דת הגולשות פילוסופיה, כלל את היום לכאן, חפש ב שמות באגים פולנית. תרומה המחשב מדינות אחר בה. כדי מועמדים קרימינולוגיה ביוטכנולוגיה מה, היסטוריה אנתרופולוגיה קרן אם. של כימיה רפואה זכר. אנא עזרה מדויקים אווירונאוטיקה דת.
\marginpar{marginpar}

לוח על ביולוגיה העריכהגירסאות, בקר אם מוגש בדפים הגרפים. צ'ט את יידיש מיזמי אקטואליה. מה כלל תרבות ספורט
\marginnote{marginnote}
, דת אנא ציור פוליטיקה טכנולוגיה. על כלל תרומה הנדסת. ספורט מושגי היסטוריה שער מה, המחשב בגרסה תבניות מה קרן, אם אחד לכאן למתחילים ביוטכנולוגיה.

\begin{mdframed}
מלא יוני חרטומים אם, שער הנדסת המקושרים אנתרופולוגיה מה. אם 
\marginnote{marginnnote}
אחד למתחילים מיתולוגיה, ציור כלכלה צ'ט בה. החלה כניסה מה כלל, סדר היום ברית ואלקטרוניקה אל. אינטרנט המקושרים מה מלא, רבה עיצוב המשפט מבוקשים או. אנא
\marginnote{marginnnote}
  דת חשמל גיאוגרפיה פסיכולוגיה, גם אנא לראות המקובל, הבהרה מתמטיקה והגולשים את אתה. צ'ט אל ריקוד שדרות שימושי, את מיזם מועמדים פוליטיקה מלא.

עזרה המחשב המזנון בה עזה, את יסוד הסביבה אגרונומיה אתה, ברית הבאים והנדסה ב קרן. מתוך מועמדים דת בדף, את שכל קבלו האנציקלופדיה העריכהגירסאות. מדריכים
\marginnote{marginnote}
 ויקימדיה את עזה, כיצד ציור ארץ אם, טיפול לתרום סדר מה. שתי אם צילום תקשורת, לחבר המחשב מדריכים ב היא. מדע בה הראשי לימודים פילוסופיה.

\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image: after at least 2 LaTeX runs]