# Margin notes in an interlinear environment aligned with source text

Tags: languages, polyglossia, marginpar, marginnote

I am creating a sample of an interlinear dual-language text produced using LaTeX. Everything is finished and the text consists of three things: an English gloss (top row); a Hebrew text (note it's a right-to-left language); and a free translation below them.

But for the final product I would like to add a margin note on the right side of the Hebrew line giving the verse number. The problem is that neither `\marginpar` nor the `marginnotes` package work very well with the interlinear environment, with the note appearing at the top or bottom of the environment.

What are some solutions to aligning a margin note with the middle of an interlinear text?

```
\documentclass[draft, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3.5cm, right=3.5cm, top=2.5cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}     
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}           
\linespread{1.1}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Calibri}

\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{everygla=\footnotesize\englishfont\beginL, everyglb=\large\hebrewfont, everyglft=\large\englishfont\beginL,
  glwordalign=center,
  aboveglftskip=-.15cm,
  glspace=1em, 
}
\newcommand{\vsd}{\vspace{0.8cm}}

\begin{document}
\setLR
\begin{center} \LARGE
Demonstration of \LaTeX\ Layout
\end{center}
\begin{flushleft}
\section*{Book of Deuteronomy}
\subsection*{ Chapter 8 \textemdash\ The Seven Species of the Land of Israel} 
\end{flushleft} 
\setRL
\begingl
\gla {And you will keep} {the commandments} {the LORD} {your God} {to walk} {in his ways} {and to fear} him //
\glb וְשָׁמַרְתָּ, אֶת-מִצְו‍ֹת השם אֱלֹהֶיךָ, לָלֶכֶת בִּדְרָכָיו, וּלְיִרְאָה אֹתוֹ //
 \glft And you will keep the commandments of the LORD your God, to walk in his ways and to fear him.//
\endgl
 \vsd %command for vertical space
 \setLR 
\section*{Textual Analysis}
\raggedright \large \englishfont
The verses above are taken from the Biblical Book of Deuteronomy.
\end{document}
```

I want something like this: (inserted via PDF comment).

[image: Picture of target layout with margin note]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: I do not have Arial or Calibri so I'm using [`libertine`](https://ctan.org/pkg/libertine) in the following example.

You need `marginnote` release 1.2b from 22th April 2017 (or newer). Previous releases do not handle right-to-left typesetting. But from release 1.2b the following example:

```
\documentclass[draft, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3.5cm, right=3.5cm, top=2.5cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{parskip}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0em}     
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}           
\linespread{1.1}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{everygla=\footnotesize\beginL, everyglft=\large\beginL,
  glwordalign=center,
  aboveglftskip=-.15cm,
  glspace=1em, 
}
\newcommand{\vsd}{\vspace{0.8cm}}
\usepackage{marginnote}[2017/04/22]% at least marginnote 1.2b needed
\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}
\setLR
\begin{center} \LARGE
Demonstration of \LaTeX\ Layout
\end{center}
\begin{flushleft}
\section*{Book of Deuteronomy}
\subsection*{ Chapter 8 \textemdash\ The Seven Species of the Land of Israel} 
\end{flushleft} 
\setRL
\begingl
\gla {And you will keep} {the commandments} {the LORD} {your God} {to walk} {in his ways} {and to fear} him //
\glb\marginnote{6 Verse}וְשָׁמַרְתָּ, אֶת-מִצְו‍ֹת השם אֱלֹהֶיךָ, לָלֶכֶת בִּדְרָכָיו, וּלְיִרְאָה אֹתוֹ //
 \glft And you will keep the commandments of the LORD your God, to walk in his ways and to fear him.//
\endgl
 \vsd %command for vertical space
 \setLR 
\section*{Textual Analysis}
\raggedright \large
The verses above are taken from the Biblical Book of Deuteronomy.
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image]

`marginnote` 1.2b is already part of TL 2017 pretest (but not TL 2016) and available for MiKTeX.

If you cannot update to `marginnote` 1.2b please have a look at [my answer to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366044/9057): [Margin Notes in Unicode RTL](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359425/margin-notes-in-unicode-rtl).

Comment: Thanks! And now I know how to update my packages too. :)